# Unable to process array Passed as post parameter to php via ajax

Tags: php, arrays, jquery

I am trying to pass an array via ajax to a remote php script for execution.

This is a snippet from what i tried

```
$arr=["12","13"];
$.ajax({
  url:"script.php",
  data:{"arr":$arr}
  success: function(data){console.log(data);},
  error:function(data){console.log("error in xhr");},
  complete:function(data){},cache: false,type: "POST",dataType: 'json'
})

<?php 
$return['arr']=json_decode($_POST['arr']);
echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

I caught the error in firebug : json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given.

However when i process the same php script alone.. it works fine!

Where am i going wrong  and what would be the best way to handle the array ?

Comment: You are passing an array not a json string.

Comment: do i need to do a JSON.stringify on the array? Can you suggest any other way of passing and processing the array? Basically i have no control on the array. Its the format in which a module returns me the result. So i dont really have a control on that. However i can change the way i am handling it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
data:{"arr":JSON.stringify($arr)}
```

let me know is this helpfull?.

Comment: Ahh .. this worked.. I tried this before and tried to see the outcome of the operation in the console. Didnt see any change in the output so i rejected the idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JSON.stringify to first serialize your object to JSON, and then specify the content-type so your server understands it's JSON.

```
$.ajax({
 url: url,
 type: "POST",
 data: JSON.stringify(data),
 contentType: "application/json",
 complete: callback
});
```